# Z-index CSS issue

Tags: css, z-index

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/home/

Hi

The following has a banner, which has a box shadow, and i want it to sit over the top of the image.

Ive tried putting a z-index and position of absolute on the div class .maincontentinner

however the background seems to mess up (with it being a gradient) when i do this.

Any ideas how i can achieve this? I have a clearfix in there also

thanks

Comment: Include relevant code.

Comment: I have no idea how to fix it. How I would fix it is make a white square of the same height as in your site right now and let it repeat-x..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [style.css](http://www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork/wp-content/themes/ValleyDentistTheme/style.css) line 431

```
.headerwrap {
    width: 100%;
    height: 218px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 8px #41434b;
    posistion: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Change `posistion` to `position`.

Comment: Hi David, I managed to change this, as well as changed to relative positioning, rather than fixed, as obviously i didnt want this to scroll. My bad spelling XD.. thanks for this. Kirsty

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd use relative rather than absolute positioning, since I don't think you want to disrupt page flow.

I applied:

```
position: relative;
z-index: -1;
```

to .maincontentinner and it seems to work just fine. What do you mean by "the background seems to mess up"? What browser are you testing in?

Comment: thanks for this Nathaniel, i combined both yours and DJDavids answers to correct, thanks